# AVAssetWriterInput and readyForMoreMediaData

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Is AVAssetWriterInput's readyForMoreMediaData updated in a background thread? If readyForMoreMediaData is NO, can I block in the main thread and wait until the value changes to YES?

I'm using an AVAssetWriterInput by pushing data to it (i.e. without using requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue) and I've set expectsMediaDataInRealTime, and 99.9% of the time I can just call appendSampleBuffer (or appendPixelBuffer) on it as fast as my app can generate frames.

This works fine unless you put the device (iPhone 3GS) to sleep for 15 minutes or so in the middle of an AVAssetWriter session. After waking up the device, appendPixelBuffer sometimes gets an error saying, "A pixel buffer cannot be appended when readyForMoreMediaData is NO". Hence my question - how best to respond to readyForMoreMediaData=NO and if I can just wait a bit in the main thread like so:

```
while ( ![assetWriterInput readyForMoreMediaData] )
{
    Sleep for a few milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Be careful not to just block the thread, here is what I was doing before that was not working:

```
while (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData == FALSE) {
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
```

The above approach would fail sometimes on my iPad2. Doing this instead fixed the problem:

```
while (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData == FALSE) {
  NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:maxDate];
}
```

Comment: Hi @MoDJ - I might be missing something, but it looks like you're trying to "sleep" 0.1 second in both approaches - but in the second one, you are not sleeping. The code doesn't mean it, and I can see from logs too...

Comment: Invoking runUntilDate on the run loop is not the same as sleeping. The run loop can do other things, like respond to async IO becoming ready or NSNotification delivery. The point here is that the readyForMoreMediaData flag could be getting set by one of the run loop operations, which seems to be what was going on with the iPad2.

Comment: So it's runUntilDate "not including self"? Guess that's what I missed

Comment: Apple provides some detailed run loop docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1

Comment: I can't believe this is the best practice. And why doesn't KVO work? I tried that as well. Grrr.

Answer (score 3):

Don't find something similar, so I left it here. **Swift 4** solution.
Would better using precise technique to solve that problem. F.e. using NSCondition:

```
func startRecording() {
        // start recording code goes here 

    readyForMediaCondition = NSCondition()
    readyForMediaObservation = pixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.observe(\.isReadyForMoreMediaData, options: .new, changeHandler: { [weak self](_, change) in
        guard let isReady = change.newValue else {
            return
        }

        if isReady {
            self?.readyForMediaCondition?.lock()
            self?.readyForMediaCondition?.signal()
            self?.readyForMediaCondition?.unlock()
        }
    })
}
```

Next:

```
func grabFrame(time: CMTime? = nil) {
    readyForMediaCondition?.lock()
    while !pixelBufferInput!.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        readyForMediaCondition?.wait()
    }
    readyForMediaCondition?.unlock()

    // append your framebuffer here
}
```

Don't forget to invalidate observer in the end

```
readyForMediaObservation?.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        int waitTime = 300;
        while (weakSelf.input.readyForMoreMediaData == NO) {
            NSLog(@"readyForMoreMediaData is NO");
            NSTimeInterval waitIntervale = 0.001 * waitTime;
            NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:waitIntervale];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:maxDate];
            waitTime += 200; // add 200ms every time
        }
```

Comment: hi jeff, welcome to the community. 1. You should point out where the asker has gone wrong, 2. You should explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Polling is not the advisable solution.

You should be using [requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput/1387508-requestmediadatawhenreadyonqueue)

```
assetWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: serialQueue) { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    while self.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        // Copy the next sample buffer from source media.
        guard let nextSampleBuffer = copyNextSampleBufferToWrite() else {
            // Mark the input as finished.
            self.assetWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            break
        }
        // Append the sample buffer to the input.
        self.assetWriterInput.append(nextSampleBuffer)
    }
}
```

Comment: If by polling you mean while loop then that is incorrect as it's exactly what the doc you referenced does: `while self.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData`

Comment: You can do the while loop after the callback is called, just like the doc I referenced shows. But you should not be looping on isReadyForMoreMediaData until after that callback, because it’s a huge waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: The doc shows the while loop being executed within the call back passed in, not afterwards.

Comment: yes, that’s exactly what I mean. Sorry I  that was obvious ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer as currently what you're proposing still goes against the documentation.