# iOS occasionally writes empty video file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `Movie` class that has an array of `UIImage` that I write to an H264 file. It works but occasionally it will write a video file that does not contain any content, but the file size is still set to a non-zero size.

Here is the code where I do the writing. I am pretty new to iOS development so this was copied from the internet so I may not fully understand what it is doing. Hopefully someone can suggest a better way of doing this.

`frame` is a `UIImage` instance in the loop

```
func writeAnimationToMovie() {
    var error: NSError?

    writer.startWriting()
    writer.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)

    var buffer: CVPixelBufferRef

    var frameCount = 0
    for frame in self.photos {
        buffer = createPixelBufferFromCGImage(frame.CGImage)

        var appendOk = false
        var j = 0
        while (!appendOk && j < 30) {
            if pixelBufferAdaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData {
                let frameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(frameCount), Int32(fps))
                appendOk = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(buffer, withPresentationTime: frameTime)
                // appendOk will always be false
                NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.05)
            } else {
                NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
            }
            j++
        }
        if (!appendOk) {
            println("Doh, frame \(frame) at offset \(frameCount) failed to append")
        }

        frameCount++
    }

    input.markAsFinished()

    writer.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({
        if self.writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Failed {
            println("oh noes, an error: \(self.writer.error.description)")
        } else {
            let content = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(self.fileURL.path!)
            println("wrote video: \(self.fileURL.path) at size: \(content?.length)")
        }
    })
}

func createPixelBufferFromCGImage(image: CGImageRef) -> CVPixelBufferRef {
    let options = [
        "kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey": true,
        "kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey": true
    ]

    let frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(CGImageGetWidth(image)), CGFloat(CGImageGetHeight(image)))

    var pixelBufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>?>.alloc(1)

    var status:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        UInt(frameSize.width),
        UInt(frameSize.height),
        OSType(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
        options,
        pixelBufferPointer
    )

    var lockStatus:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue(), 0)

    var pxData:UnsafeMutablePointer<(Void)> = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue())
    let bitmapinfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    let rgbColorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var context:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        pxData,
        UInt(frameSize.width),
        UInt(frameSize.height),
        8,
        4 * CGImageGetWidth(image),
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapinfo
    )

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue(), 0)

    return pixelBufferPointer.memory!.takeUnretainedValue()
}
```

**EDIT** The files that do not seem to have any content won't play like the other movies that work. If I view a working file with `exiftool` this is what I get

```
$ exiftool 20242697651186-o.mp4

ExifTool Version Number         : 9.76
File Name                       : 20242697651186-o.mp4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 74 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:12:05 11:07:29-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:12:08 10:12:29-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2014:12:05 11:07:29-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.1
Compatible Brands               : mp41, mp42, isom
Movie Data Size                 : 74741
Movie Data Offset               : 44
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Modify Date                     : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Time Scale                      : 600
Duration                        : 0.50 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 2
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Track Modify Date               : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0.50 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 480
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Media Modify Date               : 2014:12:05 16:07:32
Media Time Scale                : 600
Media Duration                  : 0.50 s
Media Language Code             : und
Handler Type                    : Video Track
Handler Description             : Core Media Video
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 640
Source Image Height             : 480
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Video Frame Rate                : 8
Avg Bitrate                     : 1.2 Mbps
Image Size                      : 640x480
Rotation                        : 0
```

And here is a file that doesn't work. It doesn't have all that metadata in it

```
$ exiftool 20242891987099-o.mp4

ExifTool Version Number         : 9.76
File Name                       : 20242891987099-o.mp4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 75 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:12:05 11:07:37-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:12:08 10:12:36-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2014:12:05 11:07:37-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.1
Compatible Brands               : mp41, mp42, isom
Movie Data Size                 : 76856
Movie Data Offset               : 44
```

Comment: What do you mean by `does not contain any content`? I tested the code and it is always working for me, maybe you can show more code.

Comment: @gabbler I added some more info, hopefully that helps. Did you make any more changes to the code that I don't have?

Comment: Maybe you can show your code, make a dummy project, I don't think I have more changes to the code, except initialise the `writer`,`input`. Did you test it on device or simulator?

Comment: I can advice you to add `writer` initialization into `writeAnimationToMovie()` so that you have a separate `writer` for each `writeAnimationToMovie()` run.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "does not contain any content", but hopefully one of these will help (and if not, you should implement them anyway):

1. You're blocking the thread with your calls to `sleepForTimeInterval()`, which could cause the problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11596807/1445366) suggests moving the run loop along instead of sleeping, which is a slightly better solution, but [the `readyForMoreMediaData` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriterInput/readyForMoreMediaData) has an even better suggestion:

   > This property is observable using key-value observing (see [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i)). Observers should not assume that they will be notified of changes on a specific thread.

   Instead of running a loop and *asking* if it's available, just get the object to *tell* you when it's ready for more using KVO.
2. In your `createPixelBufferFromCGImage` method, you're not checking for failure at any point. For example, you should handle the possibility that `pixelBufferPointer.memory?` is `nil`.

Basically, I'm hypothesizing that one of these things is happening:

- `j` hits `30` and nothing's been written yet because a thread is blocked. In this case you write an empty file with the correct file size.
- `createPixelBufferFromCGImage` is returning unexpected data, which you're then writing to disk